# Postgresql: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.01" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: linux, postgresql

[image: connection error]

I am a student learning Postgresql and I am having a consistent newbie error / mistake.

After a fresh install of postgres, am a able to make a new database, create tables, etc on a db on 127.0.0.1. Everything works fine until I restart my machine and try to relogin into my database. I get the error above in the picture.

I installed with the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

apt-get update
apt-get install postgresql-12
apt-get install pgadmin4
chmod -R a+wrx  /var/lib/postgresql
sudo -u postgres psql

ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'setnewPassword';
```

What else did  I need to configure? Why do I get locked out after a restart? Any ideas? I am totally stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Probably postgres service is stopped. You can check

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

If it's off you can start it

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

To make it permanent you can set it to auto start

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```